# asp.net error CS0123: No overload matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#, asp.net

CS0123: No overload for 'addItems' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

```
protected void addItems(System.EventHandler e)
        {
            DropDownList numDropDown = (DropDownList) Page.FindControl("DropDownNum");

            foreach (numOption option in numConfigManager.numConfig.numOptions.Options)
            {
                numDropDown.Items.Add(option.Value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which line do you get this exception on? are you passing in "printListItems" (whatever that is) to this method? Is this meant to be handling some event?

Comment: Erm the code you've posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with the error...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't shown anything called `printListItems` so it's not clear where that comes in, but I *suspect* you just want to change the signature of your method to:

```
protected void addItems(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

... although you should *also* rename it to `AddItems` to follow .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 3):

I think you messed up with the parameters of `addItems` if you visit [EventHandlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) you would know why

> The standard signature of an event handler delegate defines a method that does not return a value, whose first parameter is of type Object and refers to the instance that raises the event, and whose second parameter is derived from type EventArgs and holds the event data. If the event does not generate event data, the second parameter is simply an instance of EventArgs. Otherwise, the second parameter is a custom type derived from EventArgs and supplies any fields or properties needed to hold the event data.